# How to group_by with date range

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with dates in it and some text in a separate column

I want to paste together any rows that have a date within a certain range

**Input**

```
 Date           Text
    12-01-2001    sometext
    15-01-2001    sometext2
    23-02-2015    Row3_Text
    28-02-2015    Row4_Text
```

**Intended result**

```
Date       Text
12-01-2001 sometextsometext2
23-02-2015 Row3_TextRow4_Text
```

**Attempt 1**

```
df<-df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise_all(.funs = function(x) paste(unique(c(dplyr::lag(x, default = NULL), x)), collapse = ":"))
```

**Problem**

How do I create the date range (as in a number of days eg 10) to group on. I'm sure there is a lubridate way to do this but I can't figure it out

Comment: How do you determine the range? Is it the month?

Comment: Now I don't get it. How a number of days if your data suddenly jumps 14 years? Do you want to group if the difference of dates between two consecutive days is at most 10 days? Or difference from first to last in the range?

Comment: @Rui Barradas. Is at most 10 days. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for the **second** version of the question, to summarise by range of dates.

```
df %>%
  mutate(Range = cumsum(c(0L, diff(Date) > 10))) %>%
  group_by(Range) %>%
  summarise(Date = first(Date),
            Text = paste(Text, collapse = ":")) %>%
  select(-Range)
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Date       Text               
#  <date>     <chr>              
#1 2001-01-12 sometext:sometext2 
#2 2015-02-23 Row3_Text:Row4_Text
```

**Data.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Date           Text
12-01-2001    sometext
15-01-2001    sometext2
23-02-2015    Row3_Text
28-02-2015    Row4_Text                 
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks @Rui Barradas. So does the line cumsum(c(0L, diff(VisitDate4) > 10)))  compare the current VisitDate to that of the previous row or of the subsequent row?

Comment: @SebastianZeki `diff` compares the current value with the previuos one, that's why I start the vector with `0L`.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming** you want to group by month and have the first occurring date in this month:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(month = lubridate::month(Date)) %>% # create group by month
  summarise(Date = min(Date),
    Text = paste0(Text, collapse = " ")) %>% # paste values together with a space
  select(-month) # drop the month group

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Date       Text               
  <chr>      <chr>              
1 12-01-2001 sometext sometext2 
2 23-02-2015 Row3_Text Row4_Text
```

Comment: Similar here, but with `zoo::as.yearmon`.

Comment: @phiver I have amended the question- how do I select the range based on a specified number of days?